# Does calculating the phase margin when the phase is positive has any meaning?

Tags: phase, transfer-function, stability, bode

I want to calculate the phase margin and the gain margin of my transfer function to have an idea about the system's stability. The transfer function is quite complicated since it contains an exponential term.
The corresponding Bode diagram is given as the following.

[image: Bode diagram of system]

As you can see the phase is positive for the relevant frequency values. In this case, Matlab seems to not calculate the phase margin and the gain margin in the conventional way, i.e. $P_{m} = \phi \!\left( \omega \right) + 180$. Hence, my question is, does calculating the phase margin and the gain margin when the phase is positive have any meaning, and why?

Comment: Hi Bilal- Welcome to DSP.SE! Would you be able to edit your question to add your transfer function equation to it?

Comment: Voting to close.. I asked for the transfer function but OP appears to have lost interest in the question.